# SUMIF in a closed workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I got the following working formula:

```
={SUM(SUM.IF(
    'Sheet1'!$B:$B;
    IF(INDEX(List;;MATCH($D$4;Month;0);2);INDEX(List;;1);0);
    'Sheet1'!$H:$H
))}
```

I would like to make it working if the ranges (Sheet1) are actually in a closed workbook. I found the following article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260415

I don't know where to start to make it working assuming B:B and H:H are in another workbook.

D4 is the current month, Month is a list with the 12 months and List is composed of 2 zones, the first one with unique IDs that I need to compare with the B:B range and the second zone with 12 booleans columns telling me if I actually want to consider that ID for the desired month.

If I just convert it using the Microsoft KB, the following won't work (#N/A! error if entered as an array formula and I just get the total number of lines of the sheet if I enter it as a normal formula):

```
={SUM(IF(
    '[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B = IF(INDEX(List;;MATCH($D$4;Month;0);2);INDEX(List;;1);0);
    '[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$H;
    0
))}
```

---

After @barry houdini's answer, here are the exact formulas I have (still a little bit simplified). The second one (his answer) doesn't give me the exact same number because it does add up the numbers in the H columns where the B column is empty (even if List doesn't have any empty rows).

**Working**

```
=SUM(SUMIF(
    'April'!$B:$B;
    IF(INDEX(List;;4;2);INDEX(List;;1);0);
    'April'!$H:$H
))
```

**Almost working**

```
=SUM(
    IF(
        ISNUMBER(
            MATCH('April'!$B:$B;IF(INDEX(List;;4;2);INDEX(List;;1);0);0)
        );
    'April'!$H:$H
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Excel doesn't know how to compare a whole column...

`'[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B`

to a differently sized list, i.e. that returned by

`IF(INDEX(List;;MATCH($D$4;Month;0);2);INDEX(List;;1);0)`

Try using `MATCH` to do that, i.e.

**revised as per comments:**

`=SUM(IF('[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B<>"",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH('[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B;IF(INDEX(List;;MATCH($D$4;Month;0);2);INDEX(List;;1);0);0));'[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$H)))`

or **alternative**.....(see comments) which avoids the extra `IF`

`=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH('[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B:$B;IF(INDEX(List;;MATCH($D$4;Month;0);2);INDEX(List;;1);"");0));'[myFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$H))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`MATCH` returns a number (when there's a match) or `#N/A` so when you wrap that in `ISNUMBER` you get a list of `TRUE/FALSE` values as required.

Note: this will probably be slow using whole columns B and H (`SUMIF` will only use the "used range", this will use the whole column) so, if you can, I recommend using a more limited range

Comment: It doesn't return the same number as my first formula above. Actually, it returns a higher number (a little bit more than twice the number, I get 8136 instead of the correct 3773). This is entered as an array formula (CTRL+Shift+Enter), it returns 0 if not.

Comment: I tried with some other data and the final number is always ~2.15x bigger than with the original formula. There is definitely a pattern.

Comment: Does work if I use a limited range. The problem is that range is a little bit dynamic, which is the reason why I used columns before. This is weird because the numbers that are added shouldn't be since the B column is empty.

Comment: OK, let me investigate......did you use exactly the formula I suggested? Are you using the same ranges in both formulas?

Comment: Not exactly the same, I will add the real formulas (in French) in my original post.

Comment: All right, I posted the exact formulas I have in my Excel file right now (decided to translate the keywords anyway). This is a simplified version of what I will use at the end since I hardcoded the month just to be sure to isolate the problem correctly.

Comment: OK, yes, I see - because the "criteria" part returns blanks you will get numbers added for rows where column B is blank (which doesn't happen with SUMIF), you can avoid that by adding another IF function, see my answer for revised version.....

Comment: All right, it works if I change the `=` to `<>` in the first condition. Just edit that and the formatting and I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, should be <>, sorry......but hold the front page! there might be a better way - what's actually happening is that the blanks in col B are being treated as zeroes....and those match with the 0 returned as FALSE condition in the criteria, change that to a blank and (assuming no blanks in first column of List) you don't need the extra IF, see **alternative** formula above

Comment: It works like a charm with the alternative. I still had to add 2 other extra conditions since I need to check if the date in another column is in the chosen month, which gives me a final result of 3 conditions. I guess it's not the best on the performance side but it's running quickly so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that list and months are named ranges in the closed workbook. This being the case you cannot reference named ranges in a closed workbook. Convert your use of `List` and `Month` to actual cell references in the closed workbook.

Comment: List and Month are in the current workbook, not the closed one. Only the B:B and H:H ranges from Sheet1 are in a different workbook.